# Division of responsibility for UIPickerView delegate and datasource

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit

Am learning about UIPickerView and how it some methods are handled in delegate and some in datasource.

Methods handled by delegate:

Directions for drawing rectangles for items,
pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent
Row values (strings or views)

Methods handled by datasource:

Number of components,
pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent,
numberOfComponentsInPickerView

Questions:
Is there an easy way to remember which methods are handled by delegate and which are handled by datasource?
Why are some UIPickerView methods handled by delegate and some by datasource, and why are they divided between the two that way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

UIPickerView and UITableView share a very similar design in terms of having supporting delegate and datasource objects. The delegate object usually handles user interaction (or the consequence of user interaction) with the picker/table, while the datasource object, as the name might suggest, provides the specifications and content of the picker/table view.

In practice, you typically make the containing UIViewController both the delegate and the datasource and implement both sets of protocol methods in the view controller.